# Cron Job for Scheduled Reminders Failing

Tags: cron, scheduled-reminders

This CRON job worked well for a long time and all of a sudden stopped working.  No database changes were made.  Here is the setup of the job and the result.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

Entity: Job Action: send_reminder
Summary
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: syntax error
Details

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message:
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: syntax error

Comment: I'm guessing this happened after you upgraded CiviCRM? What version did you upgrade to?

Comment: Sounds likely to be a message template that worked fine on an earlier version but doesn't any more because of the way Smarty is handled. If you check the logs for the scheduled job, you should get info on which particular message couldn't be sent and it should give a line number (look for curly braces ({}) that aren't used for Smarty, often CSS).

Comment: @Coleman 6,  I did not upgrade.

Comment: @Lars SG This is what is in the log of the scheduled reminders job.   Not sure how to read that message.
Send Scheduled Reminders 
Entity: Job Action: send_reminder
Summary
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: syntax error
Details
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
Full message: 
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: syntax error

Comment: Sounds like a different problem then. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.  One of the scheduled reminders had a date and a conditional parameter in it which CIVI could not handle.  Everything back in working order.  Thanks for your help.